# Redirect stderr and stdout from ffmpeg to a file in Python with subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I am trying to redirect both the stderr and stdout of a ffmpeg command to a file and to suppress them when executing the Python script. This is my code:

```
import subprocess, shlex

cmd = 'ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -c:a copy enc_out.mp4'

with open("ffmpeg_out.txt", 'w') as log:
    ffmpeg_cmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ffmpeg_stdout = ffmpeg_cmd.communicate()
    for i in range(len(ffmpeg_stdout) - 1):
        log.write(str(ffmpeg_stdout[i]) + "\n")
```

So in general I want to do something similar to `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -c:a copy enc_out.mp4 &> ffmpeg_out.txt`. So currently in the ffmpeg_stdout I have only `(b'', None)` and the stdout and stderr are both printed when executing the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[oguzismail's answer](/a/53223999/874188) is probably superior in this particular case, but just for the record, it's not hard at all.

```
with open("ffmpeg_out.txt", 'w') as log:
    ffmpeg_cmd = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), 
        stdout=log, stderr=log)
```

Notice also the [preference for `subprocess.run()` over raw `Popen`.](/a/51950538/874188) (Probably add `check=True` as well.)

Comment: More tangentially, `shlex.split()` doesn't do anything you can't do yourself here. Just replace the spaces with `', '` and make the command a list.

Comment: @tripleee actually the command I want to execute is way longer, so this is saving me some time and also in the past I was constantly missing to put the `,` so the script was crashing and I needed to look where I have missed to put one...

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` can redirect stderr to a file on its own, and since it doesn't print anything necessary to stdout in most cases, this would be a useful workaround

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["FFREPORT"] = "file=ffmpeg_out.txt:level=32"
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), env=my_env)
```

Comment: This won't redirect stdout.

Comment: What does ffmpeg write to stdout?

Comment: Some of the analytical filters can write to stdout like metadata or libvmaf.

Comment: @Gyan how can I redirect the output of the `ffmpeg` command directly to a file?

Comment: Within python, don't know.